# How to deal with Time.deltaTime to reproduce equal simulations in multiple machines

Tags: unity-game-engine, time, simulation, game-physics, timedelta

I'm doing a simulation online game where there are some balls that move over a table. The player `a`, in his turn, makes a move that creates a movement in some of the balls. I want player `b` to see exactly what `a` did.

I built the physics of the game from scratch, but I'm using `Time.deltaTime` in the calculations. I guess this is the problem. As the frame time differ from `a`'s machine to `b`'s machine, the simulation will take different values for `Time.deltaTime` from both machines every frame and won't be equally reproduced on them.

My question is: how can I overcome this problem? Should I just set a constant value to replace `Time.deltaTime`? Is there any built-in way to do that?

The main mission I want to accomplish is to have correctness between simulations, want the balls to have the exact same positions in both machines. The game time scale in both machines is important too, but not as fundamental as the results.

Comment: I think that in this case fixedDeltaTime could be useful

Comment: Is it the same for all machines?

Comment: But this is the way to go if you need time consistency. But I am giving up on time consistency to seek perfect reproducibility between machines.

Comment: @Daniel tecnically yes, it's the same for all machines cause FixedUpdate is called on a reliable timer, independent of the frame rate